# Making a get request to the WMATA API from node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, https, get, request

I am getting a 400 response code when I make a GET call to the WMATA API from a node server.

Here's the API doc: https://developer.wmata.com/docs/services/5476365e031f590f38092508/operations/5476365e031f5909e4fe331d

Initially I was using https:

```
const https = require('https');
 var wmataBusTimesURL =    'https://api.wmata.com/NextBusService.svc/json/jPredictions' 
  + '?StopID='
  + stopID
  + theConfig.wmata_api_key;
if (!this.stopUpdates) {
// make the async call        
https.get(wmataBusTimesURL, (res) => {
  let rawData = '';
  res.on('data', (chunk) => rawData += chunk);
  res.on('end', () => {
    // once you have all the data send it to be parsed
    self.parseBusTimes(theConfig, stopID, JSON.parse(rawData), busStopList);
  });
})
// if an error handle it
.on('error', (e) => {
  self.processError();
}); }
```

But I'm pretty sure I wasn't passing the API key correctly.

Then I tried using request:

```
var request = require('request');
            // build the full URL call
            request({
                url: 'https://api.wmata.com/NextBusService.svc/json/jPredictions',
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'api_key': theConfig.wmata_api_key,
                    'StopID': stopID
                },
            }, function (error, response, body) {

                if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                    self.sendSocketNotification("DEBUG", body);
                }
                else {
                    self.sendSocketNotification("DEBUG", "In updateBusTimes request with status code: " + response.statusCode);
                }
            });
```

Now I'm getting 400 responses. Any help on one or both methods? The docs recommend ajax but I am not familiar with that. Basically I'm open to any method as long as I can successfully make the call.

Comment: go back to the docs and very carefully review the requirements for the request. The `400` Status Code is telling you that your request is not valid. Simply have to find and fix that issue. Then, by the way, either of the above methods will work.

Comment: I've reviewed them and I can't figure it out. That's why I'm asking for help...

Comment: What @devio just said in answer. Beat me to it! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API key should be in the request headers. Change your code to this:

```js
const https = require('https');

var params = {
    hostname: 'api.wmata.com',
    port: 443,
    path: '/NextBusService.svc/json/jPredictions' + '?StopID=' + stopID,
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        api_key: theConfig.wmata_api_key
    }
};

if (!this.stopUpdates) {
    // Make the async call.
    https.get(params, res => {
        let rawData = '';
        res.on('data', chunk => rawData += chunk);
        // Once you have all the data, send it to be parsed.
        res.on('end', () => self.parseBusTimes(theConfig, stopID, JSON.parse(rawData), busStopList));
    })
    // If an error occurs, handle it.
    .on('error', e => self.processError());
}
```